# C++ Writing text file to string and converting to double either gives null char or 0

Tags: c++, string, svg, ifstream

I have tried every way suggested hear to read values from a single column text file. They are pos and neg float values. I have tried boost, .atof(), .strtod(), get, getline, .push_back(), and more. My current code assigns 0 to cels. Almost every other function I tried just gave me '\0' for the string and gets stuck in the while loop.

If you look at the bottom of the program, I have started the svg to create a bar graph. I need to be able to find the max and min value to create a scale factor, and then feed each value through the svg.

I was hoping to use either .atof or getline as they seem most efficient. From what I can gather, mismatching variable types are an issue. I've worked hard on this and rewrote it countless times. I think I have a good understanding of what I need to do, and how it should be working, but I can't seem to put it all together. I would really appreciate any help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <istream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

string html_start() { return("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n\n"); }
string html_end()   { return("\n</body>\n</html>\n\n"); }
string svg_start()  { return("<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\" viewBox=\"0 0 1024 768\" preserveAspectRatio=\"xMinYMid meet\" >\n"); }
string svg_end()    { return("</svg>\n"); }



int main ()
{
    ifstream infile ("parsableTemps.txt");
    ofstream fout ("graph.html", std::ofstream::out);
    double cels, fahr, maxnum = -50, minnum = 150;
    int column = 10, width = 5;
    string number;
    //char c;

    infile.open("parsableTemps.txt");
    infile.is_open();
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
    while (! infile.eof())
    {
        std::getline (infile,number);
        //while (! isspace(c))
        //{
        //    infile >> number;
        //}


        //cels = atof(number.c_str());
        char *end;
        //std::getline(infile, number);
        //cout << number;
        cels = strtod(number.c_str(), &end);
        fahr = (9/5 * cels) + 32;

        if (fahr > maxnum)
        {
            maxnum = fahr;
        }

    if (fahr < minnum)
    {
        minnum = fahr;
    }


    fout.open("graph.html");
    fout << html_start();
    fout << "<h1> AVERAGE TEMPERATURE </h1>\n";
    fout << svg_start();

    fout << "   <rect x=\"" << column << "\" y=\"" << maxnum - fahr << "\" width=\"" << width << "\" height=\"" << fahr << "\" style=\"fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\"/>\n";

    column += width;

}
}
else
{
    cout << "error";
}

//cout << maxnum << " " << minnum;

fout << svg_end();
fout << html_end();
fout.close();
infile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isolate your problem. Does `number` contain a string after the call to `std::getline`? If not, the problem is nothing to do with the actual conversion.

Comment: What does "mismatching variable types" mean? You have warnings when you compile?

Comment: Would you mind showing some contents of `parsableTemps.txt` ?

Comment: Did you try stringstream? double x; stringstream ss(str); ss >> x;

Comment: @P0W sure, like this except newline between:

-2.780
-3.512
3.128
9.535
16.136
20.079
23.600
23.072
16.576
11.026

Comment: You don't need strtod or atof or anything. Just call `operator>>` repediately, reading into a `double` and check for errors after every call. operator>> treats newlines as whitespace. And don't use `while (!f.eof())`, it's an anti pattern.

Comment: It works on my machine.

Comment: @NeilKirk I have not. How will I get characters from parsableTemps.txt?

Comment: @doctorlove works as in outputs graph.html?

Comment: If you uncomment //cout << number; what do you get?

Comment: I don't know. If you have the double as a string eg "4.2" you can use a stringstream to convert it.

Comment: @seana. No - it read the input. You didn't say the output was the problem

Comment: @doctorlove Right, but I haven't gotten it to read the input yet. That's good news though! Hmmm.

Comment: @doctorlove it won't cout anything.

Comment: @JonathanPotter number shows "" in the debug window after the getline call. after cels = strod(number), cels = 0, and after fahr = 9/5*cels+32, fahr = 32.

Comment: @seana. Try removing "infile.open("parsableTemps.txt");"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `strtod()` is a pain in the ass: I also had a lot of trouble with it (since the pointer should always be at the right position, etc.).

The easiest solution is to use a more permissive custom fonction template (found somewhere on StackOverflow):

```
template <typename T>
T StringToNumber(const std::string &Text, const T defValue = T()) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    for(const char i : Text)  // C++11; can be replaced by an iterator
        if(isdigit(i) || i == 'e' || i == '-' || i == '+' || i == '.')
            ss << i;
    T result;
    return ss >> result ? result : defValue;
}
```

And in the `main()` function:

```
std::getline(infile,number);
cels = StringToNumber(number, 0.0);
```

---

For files with more than one number per line, I use a `std::vector<std::string>` to separate the different "words" (I mean the character sequence that is either separated by a space or a new line):

```
std::vector<std::string> WordsToVectorOfWords(const std::string &Text) {
    std::vector<std::string> VectorOfWords;
    std::string word;
    for(const char i : Text) {  // C++11; can be replaced by an iterator
        if(i == ' ' || i == '\t' || i == '\n') {
            VectorOfWords.push_back(word);
            word = "";
            continue;
        }
        word += i;
    {
    return VectorOfWords;
}
```

And in the `main()` function:

```
std::getline(infile,number);
std::vector<std::string> VectorOfWords = WordsToVectorOfWords(number);
for(const srd::string Words : VectorOfWords) {  // C++11; can be replaced by an iterator
    cels = StringToNumber(Words, 0.0);
    ...
    }
```

Comment: How could I integrate this into my program?

Comment: @seana.: If you only have one number per line in the file you read, copy-paste the function template before the `main()` and in your `while(!infile.eof())` function define `cels` as follow: `std::getline(infile,number);` `cels = StringToNumber(number, 0.0);`.

Comment: Oh thank you! I'm getting the error 'Candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument T' for cels = stringtonumber inside main().  I'm trying to look it up now.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the question is worded badly.
Before you do anything else, stop opening the input file twice:

```
ifstream infile ("parsableTemps.txt");
//...
infile.open("parsableTemps.txt");//<- Why twice?
```

This will be sufficient:

```
ifstream infile ("parsableTemps.txt");
//...
```

Second, don't keep re-opening the output file during the loop. Open it once, outside the loop:

```
ofstream fout ("graph.html", std::ofstream::out); //moved...
fout << html_start();                             //moved...
fout << "<h1> AVERAGE TEMPERATURE </h1>\n";       //moved...
fout << svg_start();                              //moved...

if (infile.is_open())
{
    while (! infile.eof())
    {
```

Your code as posted says

```
   while (! infile.eof())
    {
        std::getline (infile,number);
        //...
        fout.open("graph.html");
        //...
        fout << "   <rect x=\"" << column << "\" y=\"" << maxnum - fahr << "\" width=\"" << width << "\" height=\"" << fahr << "\" style=\"fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\"/>\n";
```

This will write over the previous file over and over. Furthermore you haven't found the overall min and max until you have finished looping, so perhaps you should write afterwards?

In terms of input, it works on my machine.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you. I didn't realize both lines opened the input file.

Answer (score 0):

All right, now it works for me

Your while loop :

```
while ( !infile.eof() )
{
    char *end;
   infile>>number; // Just read a number as string
    cels = strtod(number.c_str(), &end); // Can use other method too
    fahr = (9/5 * cels) + 32;

    if (fahr > maxnum)
    {
        maxnum = fahr;
    }

    if (fahr < minnum)
    {
        minnum = fahr;
    }

    //fout.open("graph.html"); // Don't reopen
    fout << html_start();
    fout << "<h1> AVERAGE TEMPERATURE </h1>\n";
    fout << svg_start();

    fout << "   <rect x=\"" << column << "\" y=\"" << maxnum - fahr << "\" width=\"" << width << "\" height=\"" << fahr << "\" style=\"fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\"/>\n";

    column += width;
}
```

Read a single number as string then apply `strtod` on it, you were reading entire line.
Also **don't re-open** a opened file for writing as well as reading

Not sure if you get your correct graph.html but it writes the line as per number of inputs and your algo.

Comment: Wow that was a lot more straightforward than I thought. So `ofstream fout ("graph.html", std::ofstream::out);` and `(fout.open("graph.html");` both open the file as well then right? ah. i see your comment.